# How many games were officially released for Game Boy platforms?

Tags: game-boy-advance, game-boy

I'm not sure how big is the catalogue of the Game Boy consoles.

I'd like to be precisely sure, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, according to MobyGames there were:

1. **Game Boy:** [709 games](https://www.mobygames.com/browse/games/gameboy/list-games/) released;
2. **Game Boy Color:** [612 games](https://www.mobygames.com/browse/games/gameboy-color/list-games/) released;
3. **Game Boy Advance (SP)/Micro:** [1094 games](https://www.mobygames.com/browse/games/gameboy-advance/list-games/) released.

For a total of `709+612+1094=` **2,415 games officially released for Game Boy platforms.**

Comment: Hey, nice to know MobyGames. I never heard about it before!

Comment: A new challenge for you, if you accept it: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/399165/how-many-games-were-officially-released-for-game-boy-platforms-outside-japan

Answer (score -1):

1046 games, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Game_Boy_games).

Comment: Which article? Which reference is used for this information on that article?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah I think the list was sourced from [this archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304111407/https://www.nintendo.com/consumer/downloads/dmg_games.pdf) (this leads to a page to download a PDF of the list).

Comment: The question was not about just the first Game Boy platform, but for "Game Boy platforms", that is, all Game Boy models (Game Boy Color, Game Boy Advance, etc).